# Remove titlebar from window like Vimperator

Tags: firefox, ui, customization, cocoa

There's a plugin for Firefox called Vimperator which is what it sounds like -- a vim style interface for Firefox. It has the curious ability to nearly remove the titlebar of the Firefox window. This functionality is accessed with vim-style commands.

Default Firefox

```
set gui=all
```

[image]

Firefox with almost no titlebar

```
set gui=none
```

[image: firefox titlebar gone]

Does this depend on something special about Firefox or is it possible to apply this change to apps in general or maybe to apps that use a particular framework?

By possible, what I really mean is possible without modifying the source code of the program.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to Firefox and how plugins are able to interact with its windows.

Comment: Could you add more to this? It seems unlikely that Firefox can do this and other Cocoa apps can't. Obviously other apps don't support Firefox's specific plugins and doing this would require something more involved than a setting in a preferences menu but it's not clear to me that it must be a source code change.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL Firefox uses XUL to build its windows. This is in turn translated into native code by the rendering engine. Plugins can modify the XUL before the window is rendered, hence the ability of that plugin to minimize the title bar. This is not possible in other applications that do not provide the ability through plugins to modify the "chrome" (window) before it is rendered to the screen, which would be almost all of them.